# getDisplayMedia "could not start audio source"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, navigator, mediadevices, get-display-media

I have chrome, version info:

> Google Chrome 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
>   Revision  5f4eb224680e5d7dca88504586e9fd951840cac6-refs/branch-heads/3987_137@{#16}
>   OS    Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (Build 7601.24544)

And when I execute

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video:1, audio: 1})
```

then select "share audio" in the popup, I get a DOM exception  :

> "could not start audio source"

This only happens on my desktop windows 7, but on my windows 7 laptop, it doesn't display this error. I just copied the Chrome folder from my program files and put it on the desktop, from the working laptop, but still, the error is there.

I noticed under the [support for audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia), it mentions that chrome version 74^ is [almost the only one that is] supported, which  I appear to have version 80.

Any ideas how to fix this, if there is a way?

Comment: I can confirm that it appears to work on my Win10 machine with chrome `80.0.3987.149`. Initially my theory was this might have to do with Chrome refusing to start audio if page being loaded over HTTP, but that, again, appears to just work for me

Comment: @timur yeah it works on my windows 7 laptop, but when I transfered theentire chrome application to my offline windows 7 desktop (64 bit), it gave the error. It could be its something in the comptuers settings, but I cant imagine what, since the audio is just the default system audio (or is it)?

Comment: well, you potentially have a few audio recording/playback devices - it may be worth checking whether you can record sound on that machine at all